# Algorithm to determine which variables in an expression aren’t necessary to determine the answer

Tags: algorithm, logic, boolean-logic, algebra

I am working on a project that traverses a decision tree. Every node in the decision tree has a formula which can contain multiple variables and be fairly complex. The application asks a user to input the value for the variables, one by one.

Two requirements of the application are:

1. The application must ask the user to answer variables in the order that they appear in the expression.
2. The application must skip any variables that are not needed to determine the answer.

If statements are in the format:

```
if(expression;pass;fail)
```

For example, consider the following expression:

```
if((a=1&b=1)|(c=1&d=1&e=1)|f=1;1;2)
```

If we already know that a=1 and b=1, then we know the answer will be 1, regardless of the value of c, d, e, and f. So there is no need to ask the user to input the value of those variables.

These expressions can be fairly complex, containing multiple comparison operators and embedded ifs. For example:

```
if(a>1;if(b<5;1;if(c=2;2;0));if(d!=2;if(e=1;1;if(f=2;2;0));0))
```

I’m having a terrible time coming up with an algorithm to do this efficiently. Is there an existing algorithm for deciding which variables don't matter in a given expression? Or perhaps just a new way of thinking about the problem that might help me out here?

Comment: It's easy to prune expressions left-to-right. More interesting cases: (1) We already know `f=1`. Do we immediately compute `1` without asking for `a`? (2) We know that `c` and `d` are both 1. Do we ask for `e`? It seems like the answers should be "yes" and "no"…

Comment: It seems to me an efficient algorithm for this would be an efficient algorithm for Boolean expression satisfiability. If that is correct, you may be out of luck as that is NP-Complete.

Comment: @rici What do you mean prune left-to-right? For your proposed cases, in case (1) it should ask nothing and compute 1. In case (2) it should should ask a and continue from left to right.

Comment: @Patrick87 That was my conclusion as well (although I admit I didn't know the technical terms). I should be able to solve this by testing every true/false combination of all comparisons, but that is exponentially inefficient. Perhaps I can run the common paths ahead of time and cache that knowledge for run time.

Comment: Can the same variables appear in different expressions? Also, it's unclear to me exactly what you're supposed to do - is it to find the shortest "satisfiability" path so you can present the user with less prompts, or just go with the first path, or something else?

Comment: @Mike: In that case, just evaluate recursively left to right, where each evaluation results in either a known value or a variable whose value needs to be defined. That can be done in time linear in the length of the expression.

Comment: @rici: I don't understand. Is there something you could point me to as an example? Wouldn't I need to test every combination of true/false for every comparison, thereby making it exponential time?

Comment: Every comparison either has a known value or not, so there are three possible values: true, false, unknown. An unknown value is not going to become known (unless there are side effects you didn't mention), so there is nothing more to say about that. Boolean operators can be evaluated in this ternary fashion, so that "true and unknown" (for example) is "unknown" while "true or unknown" is "true" and "false and unknown" is false.

Comment: The complication is the if-then-else operation (and arithmetic, if you have it). The two branches of the conditional will also have either a known or unknown value. I gather that the values are integers, not boolean. In this case, if the condition's value is "unknown", it is still possible for the if-then-else to have a known value, if both branches have known values which happen to be the same. If you do implement arithmetic, remember that "unknown * 0" is the known value 0.

Answer (score 0):

How about constructing a syntax tree?

[image]

As you can see, literal numbers are regarded as resolved. Every time the user gives a variable a value, the corresponding leaves node resolves to that value. Then you traverse up the tree resolving values til no more nodes can be resolved. If you reach the root node, then you can determine the answer.

[image]

EDIT: A `if(e1;e2;e3)` expression can be represented as a ternary operator node (has three child nodes). If `e1` has resolved to `true` and `e2` to some value `v`, this expression resolves to `v`. Same goes for the case `e1=false`.